# How to get the image source when an image is clicked using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, image

Suppose I have the following images in my project:

```
<div class='slider-img'>
    <span id='mimg' class='col-md-4 adjust-1'> <img src="images/image-2.jpg" alt=""> </span>
    <span id='mimg' class='col-md-4 adjust'> <img src="images/image-3.jpg" alt=""> </span>
    <span id='mimg' class='col-md-4 adjust'> <img src="images/image-4.jpg" alt=""> </span>
    <span id='mimg' class='col-md-4 adjust'> <img src="images/image-5.jpg" alt=""> </span>
</div>
```

Now I want to get the url of an image when it is clicked. So I have used to following jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#mimg').click( function() {
    var id = $('#mimg').attr('src');
    console.log(id);
  });
});
```

But it does not work as expected. That means, in console only the **undefined** keyword is print, instead of the url of clicked image. Furthermore, **undefined** is print only when 1st image ( images/image-2.jpg ) is clicked. When other images are clicked (image-3, image-4, image-5) nothing prints on console.
Can anyone tell me how can I get the url of an image when it is clicked.
- Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id` should be unique so use `class` instead, otherwise it will only select first element with the `id`. And you can use `this` inside handler to refer the clicked dom element. Since `this` refers to `span` you need to get the `img` tag inside it for getting it's `src`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mimg').click(function() {
    var id = $('img', this).attr('src');
    console.log(id);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='slider-img'>
  <span class='col-md-4 adjust-1 mimg'> <img src="images/image-2.jpg" alt=""> </span>
  <span class='col-md-4 adjust mimg'> <img src="images/image-3.jpg" alt=""> </span>
  <span class='col-md-4 adjust mimg'> <img src="images/image-4.jpg" alt=""> </span>
  <span class='col-md-4 adjust mimg'> <img src="images/image-5.jpg" alt=""> </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, **ALL element**s on a page should have a *unique `ID`*. Use `class` instead.

Secondly, if you dont have control on the html and really...reallly have no choice, then only you may do this:

```
$("[id='mimg']").click(function(){
   alert($(this).find("img").attr("src"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't use same id for more than one element. use class instead.

```
    <div class='slider-img'>
        <span id='mimg1' class='col-md-4 adjust-1'> <img src="images/image-2.jpg" alt=""> </span>
        <span id='mimg2' class='col-md-4 adjust'> <img src="images/image-3.jpg" alt=""> </span>
        <span id='mimg3' class='col-md-4 adjust'> <img src="images/image-4.jpg" alt=""> </span>
        <span id='mimg4' class='col-md-4 adjust'> <img src="images/image-5.jpg" alt=""> </span> </div>

<script>
alert($("#mimg1 img").attr("src"));
```

Comment: this doesn't work as `mimg1` doesn't have attribute `src`. You have to find `img` inside that.

Comment: oops, sorry. alert($("#mimg1 img").attr("src"));

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
       $('.col-md-4').click(function () {
           alert($(this).find('img').attr('src'));
       });
   });
```